# How to create a Rails mountable engine that is the root application itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I'm creating a `Blog` mountable engine that people will use as their complete application.

If someone current adds my gem into their Rails app, it will work under the `/blog` url of their site (since the engine is namespaced).

How can allow them to just use the gem as their whole application?

i.e. They include `gem "Blog"` in their gem file and their `http://example.com/` shows the application the gem provides.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a good case for a [routing concern](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns) (newly introduced in Rails 4). What these do is allow you to bundle & reuse a set of routes. So, with a very simple blogging application, you might have something like this:

```
concern :bloggable do
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

All the routing that's specific to your gem can go inside the bloggable concern. The default way to inject this into an app would then look a bit like this:

```
scope :blog do
  concerns :bloggable
end
```

This will give the behavior you already have - all the routing associated with the blog under the `blog/` directory. However, this would easily let the user change it. To put it on the root scope as you suggested, the user would have to add `concerns :bloggable` to the base scope of their routing file, and it will work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be the most simplest thing. All that was needed was this in the routes:

`mount Blog::Engine => "/"`